# Converting only 1/3 of RGB image to greyscale using CUDA

Tags: image-processing, cuda

I am trying to convert RGB image to greyscale using CUDA. I want to read the image with *stbi_load*, pass it to convertToGreyscale() where I call the kernel and save the image in unsigned char* - from where I can use it and apply variable threshold, sobel, multiple threshold etc. The problem is that only 1/3 of the image is being processed and actually affected by the kernel (the greyscale kernel).
Here is my kernel:

```
__global__ void greyscale(unsigned char* originalImg, unsigned char* d_greyImg, int width, int height, int channels) {

    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    unsigned int id = x + y * width;
    if (x < width && y < height) {
        unsigned char r = originalImg[id];
        unsigned char g = originalImg[id + 1];
        unsigned char b = originalImg[id + 2];
        int offset = (r+g+b) / channels;
        for (int i = 0; i < channels; i++) {
            d_greyImg[id + i] = offset;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the other part of the code:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image_write.h"

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"

#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#define THREADS 8

void convertToGreyscale(unsigned char* originalImg, unsigned char* greyImg, int width, int height, int channels)
{
    unsigned char* d_originalImg = NULL;
    unsigned char* d_greyImg = NULL;
    int size = width * height * channels * sizeof(unsigned char);

    cudaMalloc(&d_originalImg, size);
    cudaMalloc(&d_greyImg, size);

    cudaMemcpy(d_originalImg, originalImg, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_greyImg, greyImg, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 dimBlock(THREADS, THREADS);
    dim3 dimGrid(width / dimBlock.x, height / dimBlock.y);
    greyscale << <dimGrid, dimBlock >> > (d_originalImg, d_greyImg, width, height, channels);

    cudaMemcpy(greyImg, d_greyImg, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_originalImg);
}

void sobelFilter(unsigned char* originalImg, unsigned char* sobelImg, int width, int height, int channels)
{
    dim3 dimBlock(THREADS, THREADS, 1);
    dim3 dimGrid(width / dimBlock.x, height / dimBlock.y);
    unsigned char* d_originalImg = NULL;
    int size = width * height;

    cudaMalloc(&d_originalImg, size * channels * sizeof(unsigned char));

    cudaMemcpy(d_originalImg, originalImg, size * channels * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    sobel << <dimGrid, dimBlock >> > (d_originalImg, width, height);

    cudaMemcpy(sobelImg, d_originalImg, size * channels , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_originalImg);
}

int main()
{
    // read the image
    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char* originalImg = stbi_load("lenna.png", &width, &height, &channels, 0);

    size_t img_size = width * height * channels;
    unsigned char* greyImg = (unsigned char*) malloc(img_size);
    unsigned char* sobelImg = (unsigned char*) malloc(img_size);

    convertToGreyscale(originalImg, greyImg, width, height, channels);
    stbi_write_jpg("greyscale.png", width, height, channels, greyImg, 100);

    /*sobelFilter(originalImg, sobelImg, width, height, channels);
    stbi_write_jpg("sobel.png", width, height, channels, sobelImg, 100);*/

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: unsigned int id = x + y * width; should be (...) * channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to do `dimGrid((width+dimBlock.x-1) / dimBlock.x, (height+dimBlock.y-1) / dimBlock.y);` to ensure you don't miss corners.

I think the main issue is that your input image is being read without considering channels.
Your thread will have value `x`, but also value `x+1` (and the same `y`) at some point. But if you see how you define the `id`, you'll notice that instead of reading 3 by 3, you are reading 1 by one, because these two threads will have `id` and `id+1` as value. You need to make sure the computation of `id` has `channels` into account, but notice that then it will not work for the grryscale, you'd need a different one there (or divide by 3).